# Duplicate results in TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio

I am writing a document in TeXstudio and my references are shown in purple with a tooltip "label defined multiple times". When I run a text search of those labels, there are duplicate results pointing to the same line. I run the search as follows:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (Find), type search term and click + button (extended search)
2. Select "All Docs" to search label in all docs.

Result: the search result is duplicated, like this:

[image]

As we can see in the screenshot, there are 2 results, both pointing to the same line in the same document (line 9, `chapter1.tex`)

My directory structure is as follows: `chapter1.tex` is on a subfolder, the main TeX file is in the parent. The chapter is declared in the main TeX file as  `\input{./chapters/chapter1}`.

I want to understand why the results are duplicated because it might help me solve why all my labels are all marked as "label defined multiple times".

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please do not only show us the incomplete error messages shown in TeXStudio in an image, search for the log file and copy and paste the complete error messages to your question. And please show us a short compilable tex code (with or without errors) resulting in your issues ... "label defined multiple times" simply means you have used the same label more than only one time ...

Comment: There is no error message, it is simply that the results appear twice. I have also checked for multiple \label definitions and found none. That is why I think it could be a software or config issue.

Comment: Seem to be more a question for the TeXStudio support .... And without seeing any code we can only guess for that duplicate results. perhaps they are indeed correct .. but we can not know.

Comment: no solution yet.. still outstanding

Comment: well, have you asked the support of TeXStudio?